# Getting folder name using vc++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to get the all the folder name available in directory C:\Users\guest\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles. There are lot of links available on stack overflow. I tried those links and advise given on link.
Below is my code.

```
 void GetAppDirectory()
 {
 TCHAR wstrFilename[260];
 TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];

 BOOL result = SHGetSpecialFolderPath( NULL
                                , buffer
                                , CSIDL_APPDATA
                                , false );
 wcscat(buffer,L"\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\*");
 GetSubFolder( buffer, wstrFilename); 

 std::wcout<<buffer<<std::endl;

}

 void GetSubFolder( TCHAR *buffer,TCHAR  *wstrSubFolder)
{
WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
memset(&fd, 0, sizeof fd);
HANDLE hFind =FindFirstFileEx(buffer,FindExInfoStandard, &fd,FindExSearchLimitToDirectories,NULL, 0);
while(hFind)
{
    if(fd.dwFileAttributes &  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
    {
        //wcscat(buffer, fd.cAlternateFileName);
        std::wcout<<fd.cAlternateFileName<<std::endl;
        ShellExecute(NULL, L"explore", buffer, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    }
    else
    {
        std::wcout<<fd.cAlternateFileName<<std::endl;
    }

    if(!FindNextFile(hFind,&fd))
    {
    //if folder is empty then close handel and assign NULL to get out of the while loop else it will be infinite loop.
    //we get out of the while loop
    FindClose(hFind);
    hFind = NULL;
    }
 }
}
```

The fd.dwFileAttributes is returning value 0. And the code is not able to find the folder name.
I am not able to figure out what I missed that is causing  the issue.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what is problem. I restarted the machine and the code started working. Can any one guide me to know under what condition dwFileAttributes values will become zero. In my code i have not used combination of flags with or operations.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you are mixing incompatible character encodings. `TCHAR` and `wcscat`/wide character string literals don't match. Decide on one encoding, and use it throughout. If you don't plan to support Win9x it is recommended to use Unicode, i.e. `wchar_t` (and `wcscat)`.

Comment: Two more comments: (1) in every folder there are two pseudo-folders named "." and ".."; you should probably exclude them from your operations. (2) you are trying to navigate to the buffer, which is not a valid directory name; you probably meant fd.cAlternateFileName.

Comment: Thanks all I will follow the inputs shared by you all.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing any error handling, and you are passing the wrong path to `ShellExecute()`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>

void GetAppDirectory()
{
    WCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    if (!SHGetSpecialFolderPathW( NULL
                                , buffer
                                , CSIDL_APPDATA
                                , FALSE ))
        return;

    if (!PathAppend(buffer, L"Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles"))
        return;

    std::wcout << buffer << std::endl;
    GetSubFolder(buffer);
}

void GetSubFolder(LPCWSTR wstrFolder)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd = {0};
    TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    if (!PathCombine(buffer, wstrFolder, L"*"))
        return;

    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileEx(buffer, FindExInfoStandard, &fd, FindExSearchLimitToDirectories, NULL, 0);
    if (hFind == NULL)
        return;

    do
    {
        if ((lstrcmpW(fd.cFileName, L".") == 0) || (lstrcmpW(fd.cFileName, L"..") == 0))
            continue;

        std::wcout << fd.cFileName << std::endl;

        if (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if (PathCombine(buffer, wstrFolder, fd.cFileName))
                ShellExecute(NULL, L"explore", buffer, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &fd));

    FindClose(hFind);
}
```